# Backbone: how to access model't property through collection?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am currently creating Todo app with backbone.js. There is a input box to type a task in it. The input data is stored in each model (model is created each time when data is inserted). The model sets are stored in a collection. Now, I face this challenge that I can't access each model's property through collection to display all the tasks I made.
Is there any possible way to go through this?

```
 //html 
 <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="c">
 <% _.each(datas, function(data){ %>
   <li id="list">
    <a> things that need to be done : <%=data.get("things")%> </a> 
            <a id="del_btn"></a>
   </li>
 <% }); %>
 </ul>

 //View
 this.data = {
        datas: this.collection
 };

 //Collection
 helloWorldCollection.add({
     things: helloWorldModel.get("things")
 });
```

Comment: looks here is a mess in responsibilities restriction. 1) why you add to collection model property 2) view its not a hash of data. 3) mess in workflow. Model -> View -> template. In case of collections: CollectionView -> ModelView -> template. In such scheme you have no need to access model property from collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `Collection#each` in your template to loop through the collections models. Replace your current loop line with this:

```
<% datas.each(function(data){ %>
```

Backbone collections are not conventional arrays which `_.each()` operates on, but an object with lots of Underscore methods to iterate over an internal list of models.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see full code, so maybe I don't fully understand exactly what you want. I can advise you to change some parts of your code.

```
<% _.each(datas, function(data){ %>
    <li id="list">
        // Here you don't need to use get method.
        // Just specify the desired property.
        <a> things that need to be done : <%= data.things %> </a>
        <a id="del_btn"></a>
    </li>
<% }); %>
```

Also you could get all attributes of the Model of your Collection:

```
this.data = {
    datas: this.collection.toJSON()
};
```

But I think this part of code looks something like that in full version:

```
_.template({
    datas: this.collection.toJSON()
})
```

The main point is to separate logic of your application and View. Templates should only present your datas.

UPD:
And finally. If you want execute some code in the temaplate you should use

```
<% code execution %>
```

instead of

```
<%= variable interpolation %>
```

Have a good day.

Comment: Beautifully worked with this.collection.toJSON().
Thank you so much.
Just wondering what that method means?

Comment: @JoshuaJang you are welcome. Has this answer helped you? Just don't forget to mark answer that helped you. It will help other people to understand that your issue is resolved ;)

Comment: I haven't figured out how to mark this question. I am very new to this website. Could you help me out on that?

Comment: @JoshuaJang to mark an answer as correct you simply need to click an check box left from answer.